# Objective-c Novice - Needs help with UIViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im new to iphone development and after lots of reading on it im still trying to figure out how UIViews operate properly. I have been playing about with it and i this is where i am at so far:

I have created a new xcode project using the view-based application. I have my MMAppViewController classes and i created a new UIViewController subclass called "Level1View".

There is a button titled "Level 1" that takes me to the "Level1View" viewController. In this viewController there is there is a "next" button, a "main menu" button (that returns to MMAppViewController) and there is a label, currently titled "Level 1".

My problem is that the code i have used to change the title of label does not work! Does anyone know why this is? Here is my code:

```
@class MMAppViewController;

@interface MMAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MMAppViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MMAppViewController *viewController;

@end
```

and

```
@implementation MMAppViewController

-(IBAction)pushLevel1{

    Level1View *level1View = [[Level1View alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:level1View animated:YES];
}  
...
```

and

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Level1View : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;

}
-(IBAction)pushBack;
-(IBAction)pushNext;
@end
```

and

```
 #import "Level1View.h"
    #import "MMAppViewController.h"


    @implementation Level1View

    -(IBAction)pushBack{

        MMAppViewController *MainView = [[MMAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:MainView animated:YES];

    }
    -(IBAction)pushNext{

        [labelTitle setText:(@"Thanks for playing :)")];

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    ...
```

Currently the app runs but the label wont change when i hit the "next" button. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you bind the Label in Interface Builder to the labelTitle outlet in your Level1View?

If you forget that step, the outlets won't work.  Even after several years, I still forget this step sometimes.

--Mike

Comment: Yeah i didnt connect the label in Interface Builder and thats why it didnt work! Silly mistake. Thanks! When questions are answered here is there a way to mark it as answered?? Im guessing u just click a tick on the most appropriate answer?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) isn't a better tool for the job you want to do? That will make it easy for you to manage a stack of UIView objects.

That said, have you tried adding logging to make sure your pushNext method is getting called? where is labelTitle declared? Did you use a XIB or not?

Comment: I am creating a quiz game with 2 levels. The main menu will let the user choose level 1 or level 2. I have tried experimenting with navigationController but got confused and stuck. This seems to be working for me so will stick to it for the meantime. 

What is logging, is that declaring the UIButtons in header file? labelTitle is declared in Level1View header file. I used interface builder to add the buttons/ label.

Comment: I added in the Level1View header file if it helps.
This piece of code seems to work when i add it to the "nextButton" code, it changes the background: 
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: Seems i forgot to connect the label in Interface Builder and thats why it didnt work!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you connected the label in IB?

and if you set a property "`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;`" in `Level1View.h` you can access it from Main View:

```
Level1View *level1View = [[Level1View alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:level1View animated:YES];
level1View.labelTitle.text = @"something";
[level1View release];
```

The other thing you shouldn't present the Main View Controller again instead dismiss the Level1View with:

```
@implementation Level1View
    -(IBAction)pushBack{
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

//
and maybe the problem is `[[Level1View alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]` you have to specify the nib you want to load e.g. `[[Level1View alloc] initWithNibName:@"Level1View" bundle:nil]`

Comment: Seems i forgot to connect the label in Interface Builder and thats why it didnt work! Silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: don't forget the [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; advice

Comment: I added that as the last line in my pushBack method. Im not sure why this is needed though, is this to do with memory allocation? Again, im new to objective-c and iphone development, so still learning.

Comment: not adding to pushBack method but overwriting it. If you push the MainView then it will appear above the current view so the order would be mainview-level1-mainview-level2-mainview. At the end you would have 5 views one above the other. The 3 main view's are not the same!

Comment: Ah ok!! I have replaced my old code with the one u gave! Thanks you, sir!!

Answer (score 0):

Declare labelTitle as a property in your header file, and synthesize labelTitle in your .m - as long as labelTitle is hooked up through interface builder the rest of your code is fine.

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;

.m
@synthesize labelTitle;
```

Then your setter call will work. (also, dot-notation works for synthesized properties so you may as well use it)

```
change
[labelTitle setText:(@"Thanks for playing :)")];
to
labelTitle.text = @"Thanks for playing :)";
```

Synthesizing a property will create setter and getter methods at runtime. Read: [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)

Comment: Seems i forgot to connect the label in Interface Builder and thats why it didnt work! Silly mistake. Thanks!